# Add or remove items from comma separated list

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some issues adding and/or removing items from a comma separated list. I'm using the `<select>` form field to choose what items to add and/or remove.

```
<select name="choices[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

---

```
// explode list from database (choices column)
$array = explode(',', $row->choices);

// loop through html select options
foreach(Input::get('choices') as $value)
{
    // add selected items
    if($value && !in_array($value, $array))
    {
        $array[] = $value;
    }

    // remove deselected items
    if(!$value && in_array($value, $array))
    {
        $index = array_search($value, $array);
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
}

// re-delimit list; update database
$row->choices = trim(implode(',', $array), ',');
```

The function to add items to the list works as intended. However, when deselecting items, it does not remove them from the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what technologies you're using, what variables come from where, etc... How does `Input::get('choices')` differ from `$row->choices`? What are those things? Narrow down your problem such that this information is not required.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include that. I am using Laravel (4).

Comment: This is _much_ better now with your comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over `Input::get('choices')`, that array only gives you the user-selected items (which you'd have seen had you printed it out). `Input::get` doesn't know what *possible* values were in your HTML; it only knows what values were submitted via HTTP GET.

So, your checking for `!$value` does nothing — unselected values simply won't be handled at all. If the unselected values started off in the database then they will remain there.

Wouldn't it be better to start off with an empty `$array`? Then just copy the elements of `Input::get('choices')` into it? Then store that in the database.

Comment: This would work if there wasn't already values in the database to pre-select items in the list.

Comment: @Nicholas: I don't understand. You want the user to select items to store in the database, and to not select items not to store in the database. No? So why do the original values in the database matter?

Comment: Let me start from the beginning. The list /can/ have options already selected that were previously selected by a user in a previous session. When the user loads the page, these items would be selected already (I didn't post this code). I want to update the list if the user de-selects one of these already selected items. Or update the list if the user selects a new item that was not already selected.

Comment: @Nicholas: I'm still not following you. Okay, so you want to preselect some items in the HTML `select` based on the database contents. Fine. But that part is done. You've done that. The user has received that HTML with the preselected values. Done. Now you're handling user input to _replace_ those database contents with new contents on form submission. Unless I'm missing some facet of Laravel or of what your code is supposed to do; I'm not familiar with Laravel, but then you haven't really explained where this code slots into your application, either.

Comment: Did you try printing out the value of `Input::get('choices')`? Or other debugging output inside your loop to track what is happening?

Comment: I need to update the database (update the delimited list) if the user either removes already selected items or selects new items that were not already selected in the HTML `select`. The code I'm currently using does not update the delimited list if a user deselects an item (effectively removing it from the delimited list).

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question. Repeating doesn't make it clearer! Please address my follow-up questions.

Comment: Consider the form submission to be from-scratch. From the perspective of the code handling the form submission, the fact that some of the options in the HTML were preselected for the user is irrelevant information.

Comment: If I print the value of `Input::get('choices')` it will print all the selected options in the select field.

Comment: @Nicholas: Right. Not the unselected ones. Yet you expected to loop over `Input::get('choices')` and for that loop to include handling of the unselected ones (in the "`remove deselected items`" bit; the bit that you say doesn't work). Do you see how that is wrong? And why can't you just take "all the selected options" as your new values for the DB? I don't understand why _this_ code needs to be aware of how the options in the `<select>` were preselected.

Comment: You're looping over an array `1,2,4,5` and on each iteration checking whether it's value `3` or `6`, and asking why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Values which are not selected will not be present in `Input::get('choices')`, so if you select Option 2 and Option 3, `Input::get('choices')` will contain only them: `["2", "3"]`. All you have to do is join and save values from request:

```
$choices = join(',', Input::get('choices'));
$row->choices = $choices;
$row->save();
```